# How to implement a 'first-use'/tutorial activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to implement something like the "tutorials" or "introduction" activitys you see when you first start an app. Often it's a swipe view.

I've started to implement it like following:

MainActivity is the launcher and main activity. In `onCreate` I check in the shared user preferences if my firstUse boolean is set or not. If not I start a new Intent which shows the "Introduction screens" as desired. It all works but there is a problem. On the first use, you fist see the MainActivity pop up (you see the title in the action bar) and then about 500ms later the Introduction Intent starts and you see it starting.

Is there a way to start the Introduction Intent before the MainActiity is started so that the Intent does not pop over? (beside setting the Introduction Activity as launcher and main activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practice is to make your declared launcher activity not have any UI at all (ie. to never load a layout), but merely to forward to whichever of your real activity UIs you want to show - the main one or the tutorial one.  That makes it easy to add a third UI, say to implement an advanced/pro UI for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending the Application (class BaseApplication extends Application) and doing the check for your boolean there? Then you can decide which activity you want to show.

Another possibility would be to work with fragments inside the MainActivity and just replace them accordingly in combination with hiding the actionBar & statusBar in default and only show them when the MainContent-Fragment is shown.

I would always go with the fragment solution ;-)